# Android recyclerview not updating when removing an item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

- My `recyclerview` doesn't udpate with the livedata when I remove an
  item.
- The function `jokeisclicked()` opens up a dialog for the user which
  can choose to edit or delete an item of the room database.

The delete completes, but only when I refresh the tab.  How can I complete the delete without refreshing the tab?

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel
    lateinit var binding: FragmentDashboardBinding
    lateinit var adapter: JokeRecyclerViewAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        //init repo and viewmodel
        val dao: JokeDao = RoomDB.getInstance(requireContext()).JokeDAO
        val jokerepo = JokeRepo(dao, RetrofitBuilder.jokeservice)
        val factory = DashboardViewModelFactory(jokerepo)
        dashboardViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)


        //init binding
        binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        //recycler observe from livedata
        dashboardViewModel.jokes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.requireContext())
            adapter = JokeRecyclerViewAdapter(it, { selected: Joke -> jokeIsClicked(selected) })
            binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter
        })


        return binding.root
    }

    fun jokeIsClicked(joke: Joke) {
        //show pop up dialog
        val dialog = PopUpFragment(joke)
        getFragmentManager()?.let { dialog.show(it, "popUpDialog") }
       
    }

}
```

here is the popupfragment class

```
class PopUpFragment(private val selectedJoke : Joke) : DialogFragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        //init viewmodel
        val dao = RoomDB.getInstance(this.requireContext()).JokeDAO
        val jokerepo = JokeRepo(dao,RetrofitBuilder.jokeservice)
        val factory = PopUpViewModelFactory(jokerepo)
        val popupViewModel : PopUpFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,factory).get(PopUpFragmentViewModel::class.java)

        //init binding
        val binding = FragmentPopUpBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

        //edit clicked
        binding.editjoke.setOnClickListener{
        }


        //delete clicked
        binding.deletejoke.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO
            popupViewModel.deleteJoke(selectedJoke)
            this.dismiss()
        }

        return binding.root
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont update value of livedata at viewModel. Could you share viewmodles also ? If dialogViewModel removes joke from database than you have to return at @Dao's method LiveData or Flow.

Any way don't set adapert and layout manager at observe method - it's point less. For updating list at adaper you could create method and call in it notifiDataSetChanged() or (the best way of handling changes at adaper) diffUtils.

Comment: YES! you're the hero of the day tysm :) I wasnt updating the data in my viewodel

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do 2 things:

1 - Remove the data from your variable i.e if you're storying it within a an array then use  array = ArrayUtils.remove(array, index);

2 - run .notifyDataSetChanged() on your RecyclerView's Adapter in order refresh the view based on the values of the new data set.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: Not a. problem - if it solves your problem can I ask you to click the tick next to the answer please